# get resources other file exe C#

Tags: c#, get, resources

I want get resources file exe Without run the file

i am use get resources himself

```
 var hExe1 = GetModuleHandle(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);

        if (hExe1.ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        var hRes1 = FindResource(hExe1, "Dot", "Dot");
        if (hRes1.ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        var hResLoad1 = LoadResource(hExe1, hRes1);
        if (hResLoad1.ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        string resData1 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(hResLoad1);
```

Comment: So does this code work? (If not, what does it do) What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: i want get resources other file exe ,Without run the file @Sayse

Comment: Its unclear what you mean by that, please *describe* your problem along with anything you have tried and why that hasnt worked

Comment: @Sayse He's currently running the code in question in the executable with the resources. He wants to access that executable's resources from *another* executable.